# Delete string to the right in PHP

Tags: php, substr

The below code deletes to the left and not to the right.

Actual code:

```
$citygen=substr($citygen,strrpos($citygen,'&fbclid='));
```

Example:

```
?geo&moyobamba&fbclid=fdfdsfddsfds4324
```

I need to delete to the right from `&fbclick=` (since sometimes these numbers change)

Comment: Hey, could you tell me what you are trying to accomplish? For example, do you only want the value `geo&moyobamba`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `$start` parameter to [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), so it is fetching characters from the location of `&fblcid` onwards. Try this instead:

```
$citygen = '?geo&moyobamba&fbclid=fdfdsfddsfds4324';
$citygen = substr($citygen,0,strrpos($citygen,'&fbclid='));
echo $citygen;
```

Output:

```
?geo&moyobamba
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eE8uL)

Comment: Thanks excellent solution!
I made this solution but yours is simplified in 1 line and without creating another variable! thanks!

`$fbclidcitygen=substr($geodefense,strrpos($geodefense,'&fbclid='));
$geodefense = str_replace($fbclidcitygen, '', $geodefense);`